# Compiling cuda from command line - win32

Tags: windows, command-line, cuda

I don't want the whole VS install, especially since it would eat up most of my C space, so I grabbed the SDK.  I've also installed the cuda SDK.  I'm running into a rather absurd problem though:

```
d:\cuda\class>nvcc --cubin unit1-1.cu
unit1-1.cu
unit1-1.cu
tmpxft_00001224_00000000-5_unit1-1.cudafe1.gpu
tmpxft_00001224_00000000-11_unit1-1.cudafe2.gpu
'nvopencc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

d:\cuda\class>nvopencc
nvopencc: no input files
For general help: nvopencc --help
To search help: nvopencc -help:<string>
```

It's saying that nvopencc isn't a valid command and yet I can run it!  Anyone have any idea at all how to fix this??  I found `--cubin` on a command somewhere and hoped it would work...I have no idea if it's supposed to be there.  At any rate, with or without I get the same error.

Comment: Not so absurd... It just means that nvcc.exe is not using the path when searching for the compiler binaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a typical call to nvcc.exe, generated by Visual Studio 2010. Looks like you need to specify the location of the compiler binaries.

> nvcc.exe -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=\"sm_30,compute_30\"
>   --use-local-env --cl-version 2010 -ccbin "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin"
>   -I"\C\common\inc" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
>   Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include" --keep --keep-dir "Release" -maxrregcount=0
>   --machine 32 --compile -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /O2 /Zi /MD " -o "Release\kernel.cu.obj" "c:\test_cuda\test_cuda\kernel.cu"

Comment: --use-local-env is the required component.  It requires --cl-version.  The rest appears unnecessary.  I'll accept this as answer though.

Comment: for me it worked doing: `nvcc hello_world.cu --use-local-env --cl-version 2010`