# Cuda Toolkit 7.5 with Visual Studio 2012 Express .cu wont compile

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, express, cuda

I just want to compile my CUDA Code through the Command Line. I don't need the plugin ability for Visual Studio, which is not supported for VS2012 Express. I Installed the Windows 7 SDK but the Compiler still won't work. I always get the error message that "vcvars64.bat" wasn't found, which seems to be a problem with the c++ Compiler Version of Visual Studio. 
Is there a way getting around that Problem?
I was trying to compile by using the folowing lines:

```
nvcc beispielklasse.cu -run -ccbin "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/bin" -arch=compute_30
```

or after installing the SDK:

```
nvcc beispielklasse.cu -run -ccbin "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin" -arch=compute_30 --cl-version 2010
```

Comment: Did you have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804473/compiling-cuda-from-command-line-win32

Comment: Visual studio express doesn't have 64 bit support. You either need to do what is linked in the duplicate answer, or use the full visual studio version with 64 bit support, or restrict yourself to 32 bit builds